# Howto find index partition of a record in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, partition

Is it possible to find the index partition of a record in oracle. ie., to which index partition a record belongs to?

Comment: What kind of partition do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible by querying

```
select p.partition_name, c.column_name, p.high_value
  from user_part_key_columns c
  join user_tab_partitions p on p.table_name = c.name
 where p.table_name = upper('&MyTable'); -- your table name comes here
```

and then looking up your table by

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where id = MyID
   and MyKeyColumn < MyHighValue; -- consider the least satisfying value
```

where `MyKeyColumn` is counterpart for `c.column_name` and `MyHighValue` is counterpart for `p.high_value`, e.g. those can be derived by double-check comparison.

Comment: This works only for `LOCAL` indexes. Better use view `USER_IND_PARTITIONS` which is more generic. However, partitioned indexes (i.e. indexes where partition key for index is different to partition key for underlying table) are rather uncommon, so your solution should work in almost all cases.

Comment: `MyKeyColumn < MyHighValue` would apply for RANGE or INTERVAL partition. In case of LIST partition you have to use `MyKeyColumn = MyHighValue` and for HASH or even REFERENCE partition it would become more complex.